# line that has no number in it

Tags: text-processing

I have a file named `textfile` and has a content:

```
420_DA6_AB_ClassExercise1_2018.docx
420_DA6_AB_ClassExercise2_2018.docx
A Newbies Initiation To Linux.pdf
Exercises UNIX Chapter 1.pdf
Linux Handout 2018 - Chapter 1.pdf
Linux Handout 2018 - Chapter 2.pdf
Linux Handout 2018 - Chapter 3.pdf
Linux Handout 2018 - Chapter 4.pdf
Linux Handout 2018 - Chapter 5.pdf
Linux Handout 2018 - Chapter 6.pdf
SSHSecureShellClient-3.2.9.exe
```

How can I search a line that has no numbers in it?

Comment: grep -v [0-9] filename

Comment: ... although I'd suggest quoting the expression `'[0-9]'` to avoid surprises if the directory happens to contain a single-digit named file